# Hover plotly JS and array to string error

Tags: javascript, php, plotly.js

I get data from an api and structure it and make it ready to send to JS with ajax request and plot those data. Everything works fine until i add one line which shows detail when hovering on the line graph. The error i get in php is notice array to string conversion. One other possibility is to add that one line in data object that i get in JS, but i havent been able to that either.

You can see the relevant code below:

Plotly js website shows it like this:

```
   var data = [
    {

    x: [1,2,3,4,5],
    y: [2.02825,1.63728,6.83839,4.8485,4.73463],
    type: 'scatter',
    hovertemplate: '<i>Price</i>: $%{y:.2f}' +
                    '<br><b>X</b>: %{x}<br>'

},
```

My PHP code:

```
    $data = [ [
        "x" => $this->x,
        "y" => $this->y,
        "type" => "scatter",

         //below here is that one line that causes problem, In js it should look exactly like Plotly example
        "hovertemplate" => '<i>Price</i>: %{'.$this->y.':.2f}<br><b>Date</b>: %{'.$this->x.'}<br>'     

    ] ];
    $out = json_encode($data); 
    echo "{$out}";
```

When i do print_r($data) it shows right x: and y: but i get two errors (array to string.... ) and at the end of line it shows this:

```
[hovertemplate] => price: %[Array]
Date: %[Array]
```

How i can i fix this problem?

Comment: you can't concatenate an array with a string like that, you have to transform your `$this->x` array to a string ; you may do it with `implode` for example, or through `json_encode` if appropriate

Comment: @Pierre it doesnt work like that. I changed it to this and it shows nothing, not even error: "hovertemplate" => '<i>Price</i>: %{'.implode($this->y).':.2f}<br><b>Date</b>: %{'.implode($this->x).'}<br>'

Comment: your `implode` syntax is totally wrong. Please refer to the php doc, and look in your server error log, you should have a nice error logged here.

Comment: @Pierre But in plotly example they only refer to the y and x! Why cant i do the same in here in my example tho? I did this syntax now implode(",",$this->y). i get the values when i print it in php. but there arent any graph showing.

Comment: @Pierre this is how that row looks: [hovertemplate] => <i>Price</i>: %{9.9206,10.1643,9.9507,10.4375,9.683..........

Comment: in the plotly.js sample, the hovertemplate is a regular string, with a template of their own invention, just copy/paste it. I didn't catch that when reading first your question. Just use `"hovertemplate" => '<i>Price</i>: $%{y:.2f}<br><b>X</b>: %{x}<br>'`

Comment: Ok thanks that worked! i didnt even tried to that first!